# Why do I get "nodemon cannot be loaded" in my VS Code terminal?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I installed Nodemon locally and globally, but in both cases I get the same error:

> Nodemon : File C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For 
>    more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
>
> ```
> At line:1 char:1
> + nodemon Books.js
> + ~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess.
> ```

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you follow that link and read the mentioned documentation?

Comment: No. I didn't read it, because I got mad

Comment: Alright well maybe start by calming down, then doing what the message tells you to.

Comment: Hey roman, it's all about execution plolicies, can you actually try to use command line instead of powershell and try to run?

Answer (score 12):

Hello please follow these you can solve this,
-> open Admin PowerShell
type these commands.
1)Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
2)Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
3)Get-ExecutionPolicy
4)Exit

maybe your problem solve

Comment: is it a secure solution? cuz the powershell itself gives me a warning

Comment: Only step 1 is necessary. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2).

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered this problem before and solved it like this:-

go to package.json, then attachment this to scripts:-

"start": "node app",
"dev": "nodemon app"

it will be like this

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node app",
"dev": "nodemon app"},
```

then write in terminal **npm run dev**

**note:** app refer to the file name of your entry point

Answer (score 3):

#You need to change the execution policy by doing these

- open windows powershell(RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR)
- Type - Get-ExecutionPolicy
  -> you will get 'Restricted'
  -Type - Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
- type Y  and hit enter
- Now check if it changed to Unrestricted by typing Get-ExecutionPolicy
  -> you should get Unrestricted

## go to VS code studio and in the terminal:

- npm i nodemon -g(-g for globally installing it)
  -check installation by typing "nodemon -v"
  -> you will get the version installed now

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

In the package.json, replace scripts with this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app",
    "dev": "nodemon app"   },
```

Now, open the terminal and type:
**npm run dev**

Answer (score 1):

On the terminal run this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score -1):

can u try to create "bash terminal"
1 New terminal
2 Create bash teminal